# saving an image into directory c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to add an image into a directory by using c#. I'm going to use this image to display in a gridview. I wrote the code but I'm getting an error and I couldn't solve it. I have a directoy called images. This is where I'm getting error FileUpload1.SaveAs (Server.MapPath("images/" + FileName). It says C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1\images\im1.jpg' part of path couldn't be found. Here is my code:

```
string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + FileName));
String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Books (Book_Name,Author_Name,FileName, FilePath, In_Lib) VALUES (@BN,@AN,@FileName, @FilePath,@LIB)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BN", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AN", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "images/" + FileName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIB", "YES");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Comment: please note, when you upload this to a server you may have to give your app permission to write to the folder you are saving to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save into a non existing directory.

You need to create the directory hierarchy before you can save to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I created folder inside my website now it is working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/") + "\\images\\" + FileName);`

Sample code

```
Server.MapPath(".") returns D:\WebApps\shop\products
Server.MapPath("..") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("~") returns D:\WebApps\shop
Server.MapPath("/") returns C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
Server.MapPath("/shop") returns D:\WebApps\shop
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have the problem in your path.

Check whether you have a folder name `images` in your website.

if it is try something like `Server.MapPath("~/images/"+FileName);`

Also have a look at this article about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string cntPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
FileUpload1.SaveAs(cntPath + "\\images\\" + FileName);
```

I do this in one of my C# apps and it works alright.